# Regular expression in node js

Tags: regex, node.js

I'm trying to strip out facebook.com from a URL. Can someone please help me with the RegEx to do this in NodeJs and express?

"http://www.facebook.com/RalphLauren"

I need to be left with "RalphLauren" as a string.

Thanks in advance!!!

Update:

This did the trick for what I wanted:

var url = 'http://www.facebook.com/RalphLauren';
var name = url.substr(url.lastIndexOf('/')+1);

Comment: This did the trick for what I wanted:

var url = 'http://www.facebook.com/RalphLauren';
var name = url.substr(url.lastIndexOf('/')+1);

Comment: That's a brittle solution. Consider the URL `facebook.com/path/path`.

Answer (score 4):

No need for a regular expression. Use the [`parse`](http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/url.html) method of the `URL` module and extract the `path`.

```
var parts = url.parse("http://www.facebook.com/RalphLauren");
console.log(parts.path); // '/RalphLauren'
```

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
var newString = "http://www.facebook.com/RalphLauren".replace( /http:\/\/(www.)?facebook.com\/(.+)$/, "$2" );
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `replace` method on strings

```
var url = "http://www.facebook.com/RalphLauren";
url.replace(/http:\/\/.*\.facebook\.com/, '');
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace